# Golang: making the entire package OS specific

Tags: go

While I learnt that I can use go build tags (`// +build windows`) or filename suffix (`source_windows.go`) to make a go source file to be OS specific, is there a way to make all source files inside a package directory to be OS specific?

Guess: would a package name `mypackage_windows` make all files under the package dir Windows only?

If the above guess doesn't work, do I have to make an extra level of indirection such as `mypackage_usecase_windows.go`, which contains the respective import statement: `import "mymodule/mypackage_windows"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the only way is to make all files inside that package follow file name pattern or have desired [build constraints](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Build_constraints) in them. File name pattern based [build constraints](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Build_constraints) work only at source file level.

It doesn't make much sense to have and maintain N implementations of the same `mypackage` with OS or achitecture specific code. Current tooling gives you a way to have one `mypackage` and based on OS or achitecture decide how to implement its features (in platform specific source files inside that package).

Comment: what if the os specific package is developed and maintained by another team/person, while they are also "internal", so they don't get the chance to "publish" the package on github.com or the sorts? my use case might be that I literally have to COPY their package directory to my project (I know this is BAD, but the other team is using p4, so I had to create a script to sync from p4 to a directory inside my project) - so, it seems an-extra-level-of-indirection approach might work?

Comment: @Dejavu IMO then it should be considered as a different package completely with its own name and interface perhaps; and imported from build constrained file for that specific OS and/or architecture. I think current tools address problem of having OS/arch specific implementation of common `mypackage` external facing interface.